# How to attach the Konvajs Transformer to multiple shapes without groupping them?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs, konva

I'm working on a Konvajs based designer tool project where u'll be able to select multiple shapes with MouseClick+CntrlKey.

The idea is that once the first shape is selected, the Transformer is created an attached to it. If u're holding CntrlKey and click over other shapes the Transformer will be updated (with forceUpdate()) to include those too.

Thanks to [this tutorial](https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Force_Update.html) I've managed to attach the Transformer to a newly created temporary group where all shapes are being added one by one when they get selected. As soon as u clear the selection, the shapes are removed from that group.

The problem with adding shapes to a temporary group is that u cannot keep the shapes original z-index during the time they still in that group, so they all are moved to the top. That's why I'm trying to find a way to attach the Transformer to multiple shapes directly without adding them into a group.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From `konva@5.0.0` it is possible to attach several nodes:

```js
const tr = new Konva.Transformer();
layer.add(tr);

tr.nodes([shape1, shape2]);
layer.draw();
```

https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Basic_demo.html